# ¿Como hago para que salga valor true o false en el metodo esVocal()? Java POO

Tags: java, poo

Definí la clase Letra que tenga un atributo de tipo char. 
Desarrolla un método llamado
`esVocal()` que devuelva true o false según corresponda.

Mi duda es que no se hice bien el método `esVocal()`, por que aca tengo que usar `switch` , y no se si lo realice de la manera correcta.

Dentro de cada case puse un `if` diciendo si la variable letra es igual a : a, e , i, o , u es vocal , puse dentro que el estado es verdadero para cuando yo ingrese una vocal me salga true . Y en el otro case puse lo mismo pero si la variable letra es distinto de las vocales , asi me sale false ya que si ingreso una consonante me tiene que tirar false , pero siempre me tira false .

```
public class Letra {

private char letra;
private boolean valor1 ;
private boolean valor ; 



public Letra(char letra) {

    this.letra =letra;
    this.valor = false;
}

public boolean esVocal(int letra) {

    switch(letra) {

    case 1 :

         if ( letra == 'a' || letra == 'A' ||
         letra == 'e' || letra == 'E' ||
         letra == 'i' || letra == 'I' ||
         letra == 'o' || letra == 'O' ||
         letra == 'u' || letra == 'U' ) {

             valor = true;


            }

        break;

    case 2:

         if ( letra != 'a' || letra != 'A' ||
         letra != 'e' || letra != 'E' ||
         letra != 'i' || letra != 'I' ||
         letra != 'o' || letra != 'O' ||
         letra != 'u' || letra != 'U' ) {

            valor = false;
            }

        break;


        default : System.out.println("Error!");

        break;



    }

    return this.valor;


}

}
```

---

```
public class PruebaLetra {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Letra l1  = new Letra ('A');


    System.out.println(l1.esVocal(2));

}

}
```

Comment: Hola computer96, En realidad no necesitas en realidad el switch ya que puedes usar la validación en el case 1,  si coincide retornas true, en caso contrario false, agregué respuesta, saludos.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

En realidad únicamente necesitas validar si la letra que definiste al instanciar la clase `Letra` es una vocal, por lo tanto no necesitas el `switch`.

Si coincide con esta condición es una vocal, en caso contrario retornas un valor `false`:

```
          if ( letra == 'a' || letra == 'A' ||
             letra == 'e' || letra == 'E' ||
             letra == 'i' || letra == 'I' ||
             letra == 'o' || letra == 'O' ||
             letra == 'u' || letra == 'U' ) {
                 //*ES VOCAL!
                 valor = true;        
             }else{
                 //*NO ES VOCAL!
                 valor = false;
             }
```

esta sería la modificación a la clase:

```
public class Letra {

private char letra;
private boolean valor ; 


public Letra(char letra) {

    this.letra =letra;
    this.valor = false;
}

public boolean esVocal() {

         if ( letra == 'a' || letra == 'A' ||
         letra == 'e' || letra == 'E' ||
         letra == 'i' || letra == 'I' ||
         letra == 'o' || letra == 'O' ||
         letra == 'u' || letra == 'U' ) {
             //*ES VOCAL!
             valor = true;        
         }else{
             //*NO ES VOCAL!
             valor = false;
         }

    return this.valor;

  }

}
```

de esta forma puedes instanciar y el método `esVocal()` retornara un valor `true` si el carácter es una vocal, en caso contrario retornara `false`.

---

Ejemplos:

```
Letra l1  = new Letra ('A');
System.out.println(l1.esVocal());
```

salida:

```
true
```

---

```
Letra l1  = new Letra ('Z');
System.out.println(l1.esVocal());
```

salida:

```
false
```

---

Agrego funcionamiento usando `switch` donde el método `esVocal(...)` recibiría la forma de evaluar si el caracter es vocal :

```
public class Letra {

private char letra;
private boolean valor ; 


public Letra(char letra) {

    this.letra =letra;
    this.valor = false;
}

public boolean esVocal(int opcion) {

    switch(opcion) {

    case 1 :
         if ( letra == 'a' || letra == 'A' ||
         letra == 'e' || letra == 'E' ||
         letra == 'i' || letra == 'I' ||
         letra == 'o' || letra == 'O' ||
         letra == 'u' || letra == 'U' ) {
             //*Es vocal 
             valor = true;
         }else{
              //*NO es Vocal
             valor = false;
         }
        break;

    case 2:        
         if ( letra != 'a' && letra != 'A' &&
         letra != 'e' && letra != 'E' &&
         letra != 'i' && letra != 'I' &&
         letra != 'o' && letra != 'O' &&
         letra != 'u' && letra != 'U' ) {
            //*NO es Vocal 
            valor = false;
         }else{
            //*Es vocal 
            valor = true;  
         }

        break;

        default : System.out.println("Error!");

        break;
    }

    return this.valor;

}

}
```

Comment: Gracias , si lo voy hacer con if pasa que en el titulo del trabajo dice switch pense que era necesario usar si o si eso , pero ahora si me salio :) , saludos!

Comment: Definitivamente puedes usar un switch pero eso sería agregar inecesariamente lineas de código. Si requieres por "requerimiento" usar un switch para usar una u otra opción mediante el método esVocal(...) agrego la forma de realizarlo importante analizar el funcionamiento de los operadores || y && , saludos @computer96

Comment: Con un return haciendo un uppercase de la letra y enviarla el codigo no quedaría más corto ?

Answer (score 4):

Puedes utilizar la funcion indexOf de un ArrayList de esta manera

```
public static boolean esVocal(String letra){
    ArrayList<String> arrlist = new ArrayList<String>(4);
    arrlist.add("a");
    arrlist.add("e");
    arrlist.add("i");
    arrlist.add("o");
    arrlist.add("u");
    if(arrlist.indexOf(letra.toLowerCase()) >= 0){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

Recibes el parametro letra de tipo String y lo buscas dentro de tu arreglo de vocales, si la encuentra devuelve la posicion del arreglo donde se encuentra el dato que buscas si no la encuentra devuelve -1, y al tratar de hacer la dicha busqueda utilizas toLowerCase() por si se llega a dar el caso de pasarle una mayuscula no importe y realice la busqueda de manera correcta, espero te sea de ayuda.

Comment: El problema con tu método es que cada vez que se llama se va a crear el arraylist

Comment: Si, pero si crea el array fuera del método es la manera más rápida y sencilla. Ya no tienes que hacer 5 comparaciones en un if ni el switch (que de la manera que se usa en este ejercicio es bastante chapucera)

Answer (score 1):

Siempre te sale false porque envías un numero 2 al metodo y va al case de ese valor.
Otra aclaración es que haces uso de un parámetro de entrada de tipo INT, pero en el switch lo comparas con valores de tipo CHAR. Otra cosa es que parece vano el uso de case si solo hay dos opciones(o es vocal o no lo es). Solo basta con un if en caso de que lo sea o else en el caso de que no. Podes probar con esto:

```
if(letra == 'a' || letra == 'A' || letra == 'e' || letra == 'E' || letra == 'i' || letra == 'I' || letra == 'o' || letra == 'O' || letra == 'u' || letra == 'U' ){
  valor = true;
}
else
  valor = false;
```

Esta seria la lógica de tu método. Obviamente el parámetro de entrada seria de tipo char, lo restante de tu método depende de vos.

Answer (score 1):

Como referencia, una forma rápida y elegante que me gusta de comprobar si un caracter es una vocal es esta:

```
public boolean esVocal(char character){
    return "AEIOUaeiou".indexOf(character) != -1;
}
```